# Need help extracting meta title from an URL using curl and DOM

Tags: php, curl, dom

I need to extract the dollar amount e.g. $594 from the meta title of an URL. I am getting full meta title however i just need the $594 from it not the whole title. Here is my code. Thanks

```
<?php 
 
// Web page URL 
$url = 'https://www.cheapflights.com.au/flights-to-Delhi/Sydney/'; 
 
// Extract HTML using curl 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
 
// Load HTML to DOM object 
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
@$dom->loadHTML($data); 
 
// Parse DOM to get Title data 
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title'); 
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 
// Parse DOM to get meta data 
$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
 
$description = $keywords = ''; 
for($i=0; $i<$metas->length; $i++){ 
    $meta = $metas->item($i); 
     
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){ 
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
    } 
     
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){ 
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
    } 
} 
 
echo "$title". '<br/>'; 
?>
```

Comment: DOM's not going to help you across the last leg here. Can't you just `preg_match('~(\$\d+)~', ... ` in the title?

Comment: Thanks. I am not good with preg_match. Can you please help me modifying the code above so I can get desired output. Thank you so much

Comment: That's why we read up and learn. I've already given you the regex, just look up the usage of `preg_match` in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: The code above (curl) will not yield the results page where you will find the prices for various flights. You would need to submit the form and then try to find elements within the DOM but looking at the code it appears that this is dynamically generated with Javascript (React) so DOMDocument would be of no use anyway. You could try with node.js or a headless browser of some description but I don't think PHP will work

Comment: Thanks Professor Abronsius. I only need Meta title to be extracted so this particular code does extract meta title of the webpage. You are correct that it will not get pricing from various flight options as it is javascript result.